# Ford Sync MyTouch Weather

Tags: ford, sync

Is there a weather app or screen related for Ford Sync MyTouch with Nav installed.    GM OnStar let you get radar overlays while driving.

EDIT - SOLVED  - It was Under Sync Services.  After I clicked the Weather option it went to the nav screen with a radar overlay.   This appears to be related to sync and Sirius.  My Sirius subscription says "weather"

EDIT - After 5 years my Sirius Weather Subscription ran out.  Now my weather overlay is gone on my maps.  It looks cheap for just the weather service from Sirius.  It is not part of the music monthly price.

Comment: Which *exact* version of the Sync do you have: Sync w/MyFord; Sync w/MyFord Touch; or, Sync 3? Apps are only available on the MyFord and Sync 3 options and not on the MyFord Touch. Even with the Applink, there are only [limited ones available](http://owner.ford.com/content/dam/assets/ford/how-tos/sync-technology/pdfs/how-to-use-sync-applink.pdf) and it doesn't look like a weather app is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It was Under Sync Services.

After the OP clicked the Weather option it went to the nav screen with a radar overlay.

This appears to be related to sync and Sirius. The Sirius subscription says "weather".